# API claims "No such column' yet Enterprise WSDL shows it

Tags: soql

I'm trying to select a case and the product ID from the Case table. The field exists according to the WSDL:

```
<complexType name="Case">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="ens:sObject">
      <sequence>
        ...
        <element name="ProductId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
```

Yet the following fails:

```
Line:306 - SoQL code is: SELECT Id, Account.Name, ProductId FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber = '00008000'
INVALID_FIELD:
SELECT Id, Account.Name, ProductId FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber
                         ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:26
No such column 'ProductId' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at /usr/local/share/perl5/WWW/Salesforce.pm line 719.
```

I have tried ProductId and Case.ProductId, both fail. I have also tried Product.Id, that fails as well.

---

Thanks @Jayant, I checked the FLS and it's readable by my ID.

@sfdcfox, thanks for the pointer. I have an element called "Product" which is of type "Product2" and is in the "Case" object:

```
<element name="Product" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Product2"/>
```

If I try and use that as a linked item I get:

```
Line:306 - SoQL code is: SELECT Id, Account.Name, Product.Name FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber = '00008000'
INVALID_FIELD: No such relation 'Product' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at /usr/local/share/perl5/WWW/Salesforce.pm line 719.
```

Surely if it's in the "Case" object in the WSDL and if I have read access then it should be accessible?

- edit -- It's definitely not FLS. I just made Product visible and read-only to everybody but I still get No such column 'Product' on entity 'Case'

I have access to other fields in the Case object so it's not a problem with that object in general.

-- edit --

It's definitely not FLS. I just made Product visible and read-only to everybody but I still get No such column 'Product' on entity 'Case'.

I have access to other fields in the Case object so it's not a problem with that object in general.

Comment: You may like to see if the field `ProductId` on Case object has correct field level security set or not. I was able to replicate this issue if the field was say hidden vs. available for the profile that I was running the query with.

Comment: @Martin, you should merge your accounts - see this [help document](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). You should keep your earned rep from this question & your edit will be auto-approved.

Answer (score 2):

The error on the query is possibly because the Product field on Case does not have the correct Field-Level Security (FLS) set. If you don't have the field visible on the profile which is executing the query, you will receive this error.

I was able to replicate this error if the field was not visible to the profile. The query executed successfully once FLS was changed to visible.

The field being referred is as below:
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be enumerating that field, as it is only for historical purposes. Most likely you mean Asset.Product2Id or Product2Id instead. The classic "Product" object was discontinued in API v8.0, and should not appear in WSDLs for newer versions.

Comment: `ProductId` is the standard lookup field on Case object, the query should have still worked, right? At least I can execute it without any issue in my personal DE org. And with further quick test was able to replicate the issue based on FLS

Comment: @JayantDas Product was retired in v8.0. All queries should use Product2 instead.

Comment: But that's the standard field on Case and has ProductId as its name as I see.